# Set mime-type of multipart header in php curl without passing a file

Tags: php, rest, curl

Can this be done?  I'm seeing examples like

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
  'variable' => '@path/to/file;type=application/json'
));
```

But I'm unable to set this mime-type if I'm passing a string as the variable value.  The API with which I'm interfacing is explicitly requiring that this mime-type be set to application/json, but I can't seem to set it with the curl library unless I use a file.  For example:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
  'variable' => 'json_string;type=application/json'
));
```

outputs only a string with type=application/json appended to the end (which makes sense), and something like

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
  'variable' => sprintf('@%s;type=application/json', $json_string)
));
```

fails to pass anything in to the body to the server, ostensibly because it can't find the file (?).

Any ideas on how to explicitly set this mime-type without writing out temp files or writing my own post requests?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Content-Type` header via CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER?

Comment: Without curl I once changed the `Content-Tyepe` of Response Header using `header('content-type: application/json');`

Comment: @mario - this sets the content-type of the HTTPHEADER, I need to set the content-type of the individual form element...

Comment: @SilentAssassin - I need to change the individual mime-type of a form element on the request, no the response, I'm a client, not a server.

Comment: Okay, I get it. Then you need to construct a [custom multipart/ payload](http://chxo.com/be2/20050724_93bf.html). Doable per handicraft, but http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime might also be an option (it's not just for mails).

Comment: That's kind of what I was afraid of... so, bye bye curl, hello new REST client.

Answer (score 1):

Are you shure, that you want to set the mime-type in the postfield?

You might want to set it in the http-request-header like so:

CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json'),

Comment: No, unfortunately the API is checking that the HTTPHEADER content-type is 'multipart/form-data', and that the individual mime-type is 'application/json'.  Yes, they're checking both.